# jquery event not getting triggered

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

Design which I am following is :
1. Search field with a button
2. When users search for something I have a AJAX Call. Code is

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 $('.button').click(function() {
            $.ajax({  
          type: "GET",  
          url: "searchsong.php",  
          data: data, 
          dataType: "html",
          success: function(res, status, xhr) {
          if(res.indexOf("Sorry. We dint find anything meaningful for you")!=-1){
           showError(res);
          }
          else{
          $("#result-msg").hide();
          $("#load-div").hide();
           $("#result-div").show(); 
           $("#result-div").html(res); 
           }

          },
          error: function(obj,text,error) {
   } 
        });  
        return false;  

});
```

1. In the AJAX Call (searchsong.php)

   $q=$_GET['vq'];
      $param = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/-/$q/Music?    orderby=relevance&start-index=1&max-results=10&strict=true";
      require($DOCUMENT_ROOT . "songtable.php");
2. In songtable.php, I basically creates a table with search results and link for each row to perform some action, something like:

   ```
                   echo "<td width=200 class='linkcolummn'><a href='javascript:{}' class='bt-fs-dialog' onclick='toggleCheckbox(\"{$id}\",\"{$song_name}\",\"suggest\")'><span>Suggest</span></a></td>";
   ```
3. Action for this this "bt-fs-dialog" is defined in my main php page (First one) something like:

   $(".bt-fs-dialog").fSelector({
     onSubmit: function(response){
       // example response usage

   ```
   myfren = response;
   console.log(response);
   $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );

   // postToFriend();

   },
   onPreStart: function(){    

   }

   });
   ```

Now the problem when I click on the link in the search result no action is happening, its not even  entering the function.

When I simple put the link in the same file then it works fine. I am not able to understand what is the issue.

Final Code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

 $(".bt-fs-dialog").fSelector({
  onSubmit: function(response){
    // example response usage

    myfren = response;
    console.log(response);
   $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );

   // postToFriend();

  },
  onPreStart: function(){    

 }

 });


 $('.button').click(function() {

  $("#load-div").show();
  $('.error').hide(); 

            $.ajax({  
          type: "GET",  
          url: "searchsong.php",  
          data: data, 
          dataType: "html",
          success: function(res, status, xhr) {
          if(res.indexOf("Sorry. We dint find anything meaningful for you")!=-1){
          console.log("go to error");
           showError(res);
          }
          else{
          console.log("pass");
          $("#result-msg").hide();
          $("#load-div").hide();
           $("#result-div").show(); 
           $("#result-div").html(res); 
           }

          },
          error: function(obj,text,error) {
   } 
        });  
        return false;  

});

});
```

Could someone please help,.

Comment: Please check the url and dom for link you are appending. there is defenitely something wrong in there

Comment: Dont see anything there. Same file works fine when not using AJAX call

Comment: if that is your actual code, you have an extra `}`, which will trigger a js error

Comment: Cross checked in the code/console, no JS Error. Could be typo error hee

Comment: Yes the first code block has an extra `}` . Please recheck and reformat you code here.

Comment: Edited code and placed the final code at the end

Comment: @Pratik Search results links have `onClick` event which calls `toggleCheckbox` . I don't see this function anywhere. Also they have class `bt-fs-dialog` using `fSelector` which I assume is a plugin. Which one of these two should run?

Comment: Haven't put the code of onClick as it is working fine. bt-fs-dialog is a plugin and it should run both. Also I have noticed that When I place the html element with code as

Comment: I don't think `fSelector` plugin has an event named `onPreStart` . Try removing it and try again. If that correct I'll post it as an answer so you can accept.

Comment: @Ergec, fSelector has event onPreStart. Removing this doesnot solve the problem. Here is the link on fSelector plugin https://github.com/codersgrave/Facebook-Friend-Selector

Comment: Ok so the problem here is event has been bounded even before bt-fs-dialog is injected in the DOM. Tried with http://api.jquery.com/on/ and it worked; however now I am not getting how can I write my fselector function using jquer's on

Comment: `$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
        $(".bt-fs-dialog").fSelector({
            ...
        });
    });`

Comment: or you can simply call `fSelector` in here `... success: function(res, status, xhr) { ... } ... `

Comment: ok good, posted it as an answer

Comment: @Pratik may I ask you to accept my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
    $(".bt-fs-dialog").fSelector({ ... });
});
```

or simply call `fSelector` in here `... success: function(res, status, xhr) { ... } ...`